# Skipping/Parsing Special Tags

Tags: jsoup

I am writing a eclipse plug-in tool which will fix html attribute issue. UI code uses spring and few other framework. When I parse and write the file, those tags are not written properly. I also have `<script>` tag; which is untouched as expected. I want "<#", "<@" to be untouched or written properly. please help.

**Input Code
----------**

```
<#macro contentcol>
  <p data-taganalytics="trackSection" data-taglocation="AddABankAccount">
        <a href="#" id="faq" class="btnSmall jq-modal" role="button" rel="<@spring.message "linkaccount.addaccount.faq.questionid" />">
                <@spring.message "linkaccount.addaccount.faq.text" />
        </a>
   </p>

  <#if (spring.status?? && spring.status.errorMessages?exists && spring.status.errorMessages?is_sequence && spring.status.errorMessages?size > 0 ) >
        <@tom.message style="error">
            <p>
                <strong>
                    <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error>
                            <li>${error}</li>
                    </#list>
                </strong>
            </p>
        </@tom.message>
  </#if>
```

**Output Code
----------**

```
<html><head></head><body>&lt;#macro contentcol&gt;
  <p data-taganalytics="trackSection" data-taglocation="AddABankAccount">
        <a href="#" id="faq" class="btnSmall jq-modal" role="button" rel="&lt;@spring.message " linkaccount.addaccount.faq.questionid"=""></a>&quot;&gt;
                &lt;@spring.message &quot;linkaccount.addaccount.faq.text&quot; /&gt;

   </p>

  &lt;#if (spring.status?? &amp;&amp; spring.status.errorMessages?exists &amp;&amp; spring.status.errorMessages?is_sequence &amp;&amp; spring.status.errorMessages?size &gt; 0 ) &gt;
        &lt;@tom.message style=&quot;error&quot;&gt;
            <p>
                <strong>
                    &lt;#list spring.status.errorMessages as error&gt;
                            </strong></p><li><strong>${error}</strong></li><strong>
                    <!--#list-->
                </strong>
            <p></p>
        <!--@tom.message-->
  <!--#if-->
```

**This is my Parser Read Code:**

```
htmlFile = DocumentUtil.fixCompliance(Jsoup.parse(in, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

**This is my Write Code:**

```
Document.OutputSettings settings = document.outputSettings();

settings.prettyPrint(false);

settings.escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.base);

settings.charset("ASCII")   

System.out.println(document.html().toString());

writer = new PrintWriter(in, "ASCII"); 

writer.write(document.html());

writer.flush();

writer.close();
```

**Tried both UTF-8 and ASCII**

Comment: I think Jsoup is not meant for that. Of course you can try to adjust the whiltelist (http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html) for parsing, but basically Jsoup is meant to parse html that is ready to be rendered, not the templates with source code additions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify Jsoup source code, to meet my requirement. Below is the changes done, check the line comment.

**TokeniserState.java**

```
    EndTagOpen {
    void read(Tokeniser t, CharacterReader r) {
        if (r.isEmpty()) {
            t.eofError(this);
            t.emit("</");
            t.transition(Data);
        } else if (r.matchesLetter()) {
            t.createTagPending(false);
            t.transition(TagName);
        } else if (r.matches('>')) {
            t.error(this);
            t.advanceTransition(Data);
        } 
        else if (r.matches('#') || r.matches('@')) { // Added this condition
            t.error(this);
            t.emit("</");
            t.transition(Data);
        } 
        else {
            t.error(this);
            t.advanceTransition(BogusComment);
        }
    }
```

**Entities.java**

```
if (codePoint < Character.MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT) {
            final char c = (char) codePoint;
            switch (c) {
                case '&':
                    accum.append("&amp;");
                    break;
                case 0xA0:
                    if (escapeMode != EscapeMode.xhtml)
                        accum.append("&nbsp;");
                    else
                        accum.append("&#xa0;");
                    break;
                case '<':
                    if (!inAttribute || escapeMode == EscapeMode.xhtml)
                        accum.append("<"); //Modified this line
                    else
                        accum.append(c);
                    break;
                case '>':
                    if (!inAttribute)
                        accum.append(">"); ///Modified this line
                    else
                        accum.append(c);
                    break;
```